# Search problem? "operator>>"

Tags: support, search

When trying to see what is written in stackoverflow.com regarding C++'s `operator>>` the search returns refrences to other operators, and pages with 'operator>>' in the 'Related' section.

One would assume that there are no questions/answers with that text.

Google search with `site:stackoverflow.com "operator>>"` returns a couple

[Result#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833157/operator-overloading),
[Result#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551156/compiler-not-creating-templated-ostream-operator), ...

Is SO's internal search broken?

Comment: I'm pretty sure punctuation such as `>` is not indexed, so any punctuation in the search query is dropped.

Comment: Especially in C++, punctuation is important. I can give away `,` and `.` but not `>`, `+`, etc.

Comment: @marcog I understand, but as stackoverflow is a specialized site, where programming languages are the topics, these need to be treated as acceptable search terms. solutions are needed

Comment: @nhed I agree, but it means search is not *broken* and this is a feature request rather than a bug.

Comment: I guess I was using a looser definition of bug ... the point is that I pointed it out and hopefully someone from stackexchange will note it.  This is my first question on `meta` hopefully I didn't upset anyone by calling it a bug.

Comment: @nhed no upset taken, feel free to edit your question and put "Support" tag instead of bug to make it more accurate.